# Retain cycle trouble when transitioning between scenes

Tags: swift, transition, retain, skscene

I have a game in which the main menu presents the game scene, and when the player loses, the game scene presents back the menu. When transitioning from the menu to the game scene, the menu's **deinit** is successfully called. My problem is that the opposite doesn't happen (when transitioning from the game scene to the menu scene, gameScene's **deinit** isn't called).

I suspect a strong reference cycle directly between the new main menu instance that I create and the game scene which creates the instance. Matter of facts, if I edit my gameScene's code as following, I do get the **deinit**'s call, but my app crashes at runtime while trying to present the scene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    // Some stuff

    // Now the function which is called when I want to present back the menu scene:
    func lose() {
        // Some stuff

        // Delay is a helper function
        delay(bySeconds: 2.0, closure: { [unowned self] in
            for child in self.children {
                child.removeFromParent()
            }

            unowned let menu = MainMenu(size: CGSize(width: 1152, height: 2048))
            let reveal = SKTransition.fade(with: SKColor.black, duration: 1.0)

            self.view?.presentScene(menu, transition: reveal)
        })

    }
}
```

At runtime I get the following error:

> Attempted to retain deallocated object

Here's the definition of delay:

```
public func delay(bySeconds seconds: Double, dispatchLevel: DispatchLevel = .main, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + seconds
    dispatchLevel.dispatchQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: closure)
}

public enum DispatchLevel {
    case main, userInteractive, userInitiated, utility, background
    var dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue {
        switch self {
        case .main:                 return DispatchQueue.main
        case .userInteractive:      return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
        case .userInitiated:        return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
        case .utility:              return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
        case .background:           return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my MainMenu class:

```
class MainMenu: SKScene {
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1152, height: 2048))
    let reveal = SKTransition.fade(with: SKColor.black, duration: 1.0)
    // Some stuff
    // override func didMove(to ...

    // Now the function which is called when I want to present the game scene:
    func presentGame() {
        view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
    }
}
```

I've tried different things but they didn't work out (for example: setting the new menu instance in the init method of gameScene).

If I remove the **"unowned"** definition of the menu constant in the GameScene class, the transition is successfully made but **deinit** isn't called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried 'weak self' instead of 'unowned self'?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what had been keeping my game scene from deinitializing itself.

It had nothing to do with the code that I provided with my question. The problem was in a strong "self" reference inside a closure which was responsible to interpret the accelerometer's input.

If you're interested in more informations, see here: [Retain cycle suspected in closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028982/retain-cycle-suspected-in-closure)